# How to configure Grafana alerts with Loki

Tags: grafana, grafana-loki

I have troubles configuring Grafana alerts with Loki. When I switch to the alerts page I always get the following:
[image: Failed to load rules config from Loki: API error]

In the browser devtools I see:
[image: HTTP 400 bad request error]

Here is the ruler part of my loki.yaml:

```
ruler:
  storage:
    type: local
    local:
      directory: /data/loki/rules
  rule_path: /data/loki/scratch
  alertmanager_url: http://alertmanager-operated.svc.cluster.local:9093
  ring:
    kvstore:
      store: inmemory
  enable_api: true
  enable_alertmanager_v2: true
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You should first check loki api `GET ~/loki/api/v1/rules` give the correct response.